# Can't output ü through NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have made an app where I read words from an rtf file

File is loaded through this code

```
self.germanpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"german" ofType:@"rtf"];
germanfile = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:germanpath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

The files contents are

> schockierend knusprig das Schachmatt der Schriftsteller getrocknete
>   Früchte

When I output the string the characters like `ü` are printing like `getrocknete Fr\'fcchte`. Both in app and in `NSLog` statements it is coming as `\'`.

### Edit

I just tried outputting simply

```
NSLog(@"schockierend knusprig das Schachmatt der Schriftsteller getrocknete Früchte");
```

and it worked. So I am stating the method I used to output it; I am outputting word by word

```
NSString *startfrom = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"german%i",i];
NSString *word = nil;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:germanfile];
[scanner scanUpToString:startfrom intoString:nil];
[scanner scanUpToString:@" end" intoString:&word];
NSString *finalword = [word substringFromIndex:[startfrom length]];
Word.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"DK Crayon Crumble" size:25.0];
Word.text = finalword;
NSLog(@"%@",finalword);
[startfrom release];
```

Comment: Is the file actually encoded in utf-8?

Comment: i don't know. i just made it in textedit in mac and save as rtf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an RTF file, not a plain text file. Its contents are encoded according to how RTF files are encoded, which involves escaping non-ASCII characters.

Because there's no native RTF support on iOS (there is on Mac OS X with `NSAttributedString`), you would have to roll your own RTF parser in order to read this file. I wouldn't recommend it. If the RTF file is actually being used to store attributes (such as *italic* or **bold** text), you'll have to go the parser route to convert it to an `NSAttributedString` or some other format.

If it's just plain text (and can therefore be fully represented by a Unicode string) then you should recreate the file as a TXT file using a known encoding (such as UTF-8) and *then* use `-[NSString initWithContentsOfFile:encoding:]` to read it.